# java mysql , chosing the connection driver

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using eclipse  and this is my code in order to connect to a remote mysql server:

```java
package test;

import java.sql.*;  

public class test{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        try{  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:mysql://host:port/database?useSSL=true","username","password");  
        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
    }  
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I used mysql workbench and I was able to connect to the server. My mysql driver is:

```
mysql-connector-java-8.0.22
 java version is : 1.8.0_271
```

The remote database isn't an actual mysql database but I'm using connector for bi available in mongodb atlas.
Is there a way to know which mysql-connectorjava to use?

Comment: _the remote database isn't an actual mysql database_ Then why are you using MySQL JDBC driver to connect to it? Or did I misunderstand what you are trying to do?

Comment: i'm using mongodb atlas , which contains a connector for bi.  when i activate the connector for bi i can connect to the database like a mysql database.  the above approach used to work for me but now i don't know why it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

did you try mysql connector dependency jar for your java application?

If your project is maven based, you can directly add this dependency in your pom.xml file from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java.